# Apache + CentOS 6 + Joomla: You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd.conf

My site was in /usr/local/apache/htdocs.

Now i created new account in cpanel and move site to /home/account_name/public_html

Group and owner for all files are "account_name"

.htaccess and path configuration for a site are OK

I get error: "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

What i need to change to get it work?

Maybe some things in /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf ?

Answer (score 1):

Your apache is running with process uid and gid preventing it from accessing /home/account_name/public_html.

You can change group for this folder to apache:

```
chgrp -R apache /home/account_name/public_html
chmod g+rx  /home/account_name/public_html
```

or you can give anyone rx permission on this folder:

`chmod o+rx /home/account_name/public_html`

Comment: your solution does not help

Comment: Problem was in permissions for folder "public_html"
I changed it from 0750 to 0755  and all works!

Comment: I can be mistaken with apache username in Centos.